# Removing ": " from JSON-like data

Tags: regex, perl

I have a 1,00,000-line JSON text file. Manual extraction is not fair. I have written a Perl program to read each line of the file, which meets my needs.

Here's a sample text file

#### Sample.txt

```
  "key": "Programming",
  "doc_count": 1
  
  "key": "Base",
  "doc_count": 1,
  
  "key": "Experience",
  "doc_count": 1

  "key": "Electrophoresis",
  "doc_count": 1
```

I would like to take the key value alone delimited by double brackets, say **Programming, Base, Experience and Electrophoresis**.

Here's the Perl code that I tried:

#### ExtractKeyValue.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while ( my $line = <$info> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /"key(.*)",/ ) {
        print $1;
        print "\n";
    }
}

close $info;
```

By using this, I am getting this output

```
": "Programming
": "Base
": "Experience
": "Electrophoresis
```

I don't want the leading colon and space.

I have tried `$line =~ /"key: "(.*)",/`. But it is not working. The command executes but no output and no error symptoms.

```
G:\ExtractKeyValue_Regex>perl ExtractKeyValue.pl Sample.txt > Output_Sample.txt

G:\ExtractKeyValue_Regex>
```

The output should be like,

#### Expected Output:

```
Programming
Base
Experience
Electrophoresis
```

I could not figure out why the colon `:` and space and double quotes `"` are not tracked by the pattern.

Comment: You're missing a quote: `"key": `, not `"key: `.

Comment: Please note that the language is called ***Perl***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the lines you show all you need is

```
my $key_assoc = $line =~ /: "([^"]+)/;

print "$key_assoc\n" if $key_assoc;
```

Or you can throw in the `"key"` string and `",` for extra assurance and a format check

```
if ($line =~ /"key": "([^"]+)",/) {
    # ...
}
```

Note that `+` makes it *not* capture anything if there are empty quotes (`"key": "",`) while `.*` would get you the empty string in that case. A detail which may not matter, but they are different.

---

Note that the use of a single literal space   in a regex is prone to being overlooked (or doubled) and can also get swallowed if `/x` is added later, introducing a bug if not tested.

Better ways to specify a single simple space? We can use `\x20`, or Unicode `\N{SPACE}` via the [`charnames`](http://perldoc.perl.org/charnames.html) pragma.  Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for bringing this up and specifying these two.

A nice workaround, from [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-%C3%9Cn%C3%BCr), is to use a character class with space only, `/a [ ] b/x`. This both emphasizes that a literal space is intended (without `/x`), and allows it under `/x`.

Another fix is to explicitly escape it, `/\ /`, which draws attention to it and protects it from `/x`.

Comment: @MJSuriya  Great :)  Thanks for the feedback and the attribution.  I added `",` at the end as I think that it is good to have that as an additional format check (like you have it).

Comment: @zdim: I don't like literal spaces in regex patterns because they're so easily misread, and are discounted altogether if there is a `/x` modifier in effect. You have `\s` and `\h` for the normal cases, but to express exactly one space with graphical characters I know nothing better than `\x20` or `\N{SPACE}`

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you for that comment -- this has been nagging me for years, how to (nicely and safely) specify one simple space. I've always thought that there was something simple and clean hidden somewhere. It's also hard to decide between the two you provide (thank you), but I'd lean toward Unicode `charnames` ...? I'll research.  I guess another solution (which I had used) is to explicitely escape it, in order to draw attention and protect against `/x`, but that sure isn't pretty. I am adding a note on this to the post, thank you.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Right, thank you -- that's much better than escaping it. Added.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this:

```
"key": "(.*?)"
```

Do it in the regex check:

```
if($line =~ /"key": "(.*?)",/){
   ...
```

This way, the first capture group (`$1`) will contain exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would write. It scans every line from the input file for two double-quoted strings, and then prints the second one if it was there

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($file) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, $file or die qq{Could not open "$file": $!};

while ( <$fh> ) {

    my ($key, $val) = / " ( [^"]+ ) " /xg;

    next unless $key and $key eq 'key';

    print $val, "\n" if $val;
}
```

#### output